# Retrieving an items department from a receipt

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

Using the SDK , I can see that you can retrieve an item on a receipt using the SalesReceiptQueryRq call. This call returns the item LISTID , which I can then reference the inventory and get the department. However, this will return the current department for the item and not the historical department that was on the document.

An example is the client selling an item in February 2014 as a Jacket department item. If they edit the item in August 2014 , and change the department to Clearance. If I read the data , the item will show up as linked to Clearance. QuickBooks POS reports will show the item in Jackets.

Any ideas ?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Correct. QB will only have the current value and does not track history.